# SimpleJdbcCall : No function exist error

Tags: spring

I am getting Exception while executing store procedure. Exception is as below

`org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback;badSQLgrammar [{call find_spot()}]; nestedexception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: functionfind_spot()`

does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.Position:15
Its saying function **find_spot()** does not exist but I checked in database this procedure is there. I am using **Postgresql [DBeaver]**
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should cast a json to make search or use the json access query, see the examples:

```
select * from table where cast(field_json as varchar(500)) !~ 'reg_ex' and id = 11
```

or

```
select field_json->>'key' from table where field_json->>'key' ilike 'value'
```